# 2-Satisfiability and Strongly connected components

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, 2-satisfiability

I know that applying **Strongly connected components** in a Digraph we can check **2-SAT boolean satisfiability** if the problem is solvable in polynomial time.

Let's assume the problem is satisfiable.

The question: is there a general algorithm to calculate that solution relying on 2-SAT?

Comment: Is SAT-2 the same as 2-SAT, i.e. CNF with every clause having exactly two literals?

Comment: Exactly, This is 2-SAT-CNF form.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google or Code Jam?

Comment: svick, please read below comments.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, yes, there is a general algorithm to find a solution (i.e. a satisfying assignment) by using the algorithm for the satisfiability problem.

Suppose I assign a variable x<sub>i</sub> the value "true" (so that the literal x<sub>i</sub> is true and ~x<sub>i</sub> is false) to make a new 2-CNF from the original. If I were to run satisfiability on it (i.e. use the thing with SCCs to find if the new CNF is satisfiable):

1. What does it tell you about the satisfying assignments in the original CNF if the resulting CNF is now *not* satisfiable?
2. What does it tell you about the satisfying assignments in the original CNF if the resulting CNF is *still* satisfiable?

The idea behind the algorithm is to make the variable "false" if you hit case 1, and "true" if you hit case 2, and loop through every variable (keeping the assignments that you made to variables you've already looked at). Once you can answer the questions I've posed, you'll understand the concept behind it.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the answer. Basically, I've been trying to map this problem from Google Jam to 2-SAT but have some difficulties: http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32016/dashboard#s=p1&a=1 There are some constraints as well and this is my first experience in problems like this one.

Comment: Yeah, the problem you linked isn't 2-SAT; you'd have to have each person liking at most two flavors for it to be 2-SAT. My tip on that problem is that because of the constraints on how big N is, there can't be more than 1024 combinations of making everything malted or unmalted. There aren't that many customers, you could probably just loop through all of the combinations and find one that works.

Comment: Absolutely! These constraints got me confused.